# Как дать БД понять что я оффлайн?

Tags: java, android, mysql

Всем добрый вечер .Столкнулся с проблемой ,которая в целом исходит от моей неопытности ...Есть Андроид приложение которое Имеет БД `Mysql`(удаленное подключение через php скрипт).В Этой БД есть таблица `Status` в котором установлено по дефалту `false`.Я ппроверяю в бд есть ли на данный момент подключение или нет .Проверка происходит таким путем если стату запроса 200 то я обнавляю значение и делаю его true .Но если интернета нет как мне послать значение 
`false`))))???Очень нужна помощь как с этим бороться какие пути есть ?Благодарю за помощь

Comment: как послать по интернету значение  `false`, если интернета нет?

Comment: Я говю о своей тупости )и хотел бы узнать правильное решение

Comment: нет-нет, какая тупость? Мне просто нравится парадокс.

Comment: Спасибо)))Знаю я сам свел себя в тупик )))

Comment: Ну а решение? Для клиентского приложения - ловить ошибку обращения к php. Для сервера - смотреть время последнего обращения от данного клиента, которое тоже хранить в базе.

Comment: Для сервера - смотреть время последнего обращения от данного клиента, которое тоже хранить в базе  можно ли примерчик?

Comment: Вы выбрали не те инструменты для решения своей задачи.

Comment: @temq да товарищ я понел.Щас попробую по дате последнего запроса )но насколько точный будет такой расччет ?

Comment: Зависит от того какая точность нужна и в каких ситуациях считается что пользователь оффлайн.

Comment: Понтно .щас пробов буду с расчетом +-2 минуты (для меня не велика потеря)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае следует во время выполнения обновления(действия, операции) постоянно отмечать его дату и время.
В этом случае активные соединения будут иметь дату и время близкую к текущей, а те что в офлайн будут иметь дату и время в прошлом.

Comment: Привет товарищ ,да так и делаю , с +-2  минуты для меня не вика потеря .Спасибо за ваш отклик